# C++ Setting a frame rate in a game like Tetris

Tags: c++, frame, sfml, rate

So this question is a little more abstract than some. Say I have a game that I only want to render once per second, such as a Tetris clone. I only want to process one input per second, then render the new frame accordingly. Tetris is a grid-based game, so I can't just move the game piece by a certain amount times the `timeDelta` float that people usually use for frame rate examples. How do I go about only rendering one frame per second in a grid-based game? Here's what code I have so far, but it's wrong:

```
void Engine::Go(){
    while(window.isOpen()){
        if(timeElapsed >= 1000){
            timeElapsed = clock.restart().asMilliseconds();;
            ProcessInput();
        }
        UpdateCPU();
        Render();
        timeElapsed = clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();
        time += timeElapsed;
    }
}

void Engine::ProcessInput(){
    while(window.pollEvent(event)){
        if(event.type == (sf::Event::Closed))
            window.close();
    }
    //process movement detection of piece
    int temp = level.GetGamePieces().size();
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)){
        level.GetGamePieces().at(temp - 1).GetPieceSprite().move(-10, 0);
        std::cout << "left";
        moved = true;
    }
    else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)){
        level.GetGamePieces().at(temp - 1).GetPieceSprite().move(10,0);
        std::cout << "right";
        moved = true;
    }
    else{
        level.GetGamePieces().at(temp - 1).GetPieceSprite().move(0,10);
        std::cout << "down";
        moved = true;
    }
}
```

I only want to move the gamepiece one sqaure at a time, once per second, but I just don't know how to do this.

Edit: Here's the code that renders the frames

```
void Engine::Render(){
    window.clear();
    //draw wall tiles
    for(int i = 0; i < 160; i++){
        if(i < 60){
            level.GetWallTile().setPosition(0, i * 10);
            window.draw(level.GetWallTile());
        }
        if(i >= 60 && i < 100){
            level.GetWallTile().setPosition((i - 60) * 10, 590);
            window.draw(level.GetWallTile());
        }
        if(i >= 100){
            level.GetWallTile().setPosition(390, (i - 100) * 10);
            window.draw(level.GetWallTile());
        }
    }

    //draw BG tiles
    for(int i = 1; i < 39; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 59; j++){
            level.GetBGTile().setPosition(i * 10, j * 10);
            window.draw(level.GetBGTile());
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < level.GetGamePieces().size(); i++){
        window.draw(level.GetGamePieces()[i].GetPieceSprite());
    }

    window.display();
}
```

Comment: void sf::Window::setFramerateLimit(int limit)?

Comment: You definitely don't want to process user input only once per second. The game would feel horribly broken. You need to handle input as soon as it comes in, or at least 30 times per second.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Ok that sounds better than my plan, but how do I only render once per second? And besides, the only three inputs there are will only take effect once per second. For instance, if the right arrow key is hit three times in one second I don't want the piece moving right three spaces before the next update.

Comment: Set your update rate to something that feels responsive -- about 30 times per second should be fine.  Then use a counter to decide if you need to move the pieces during that update.

Answer (score 1):

You are not accounting for the fact that a user may want to move a shape in between movements of the shape.

You should allow the user to move the shape left, right, and down whenever he/she wants to, but 
not force the downward movement until after the elapsed time has completed.

[When I made a block-based game, here's what I did](https://github.com/pyjarrett/PowerBlocks/blob/master/PowerBlocks/src/PBGame.mm)

```
void updateSeconds( double deltaTime ) {
// If timer until shape falls runs out, move the shape down.
    timeUntilShapeDrop -= deltaTime;
    if ( timeUntilShapeDrop > 0 || currentFallingShape->isAnimating() ) {
        return;
    }

    // If ( shape collides with map when moved down )
    currentFallingShape->move(-1,0);
    if ( currentFallingShape->isCollisionWithMap ( * map ) ) {
        currentFallingShape->move(1,0);

        // Lock shape in place on the map
        currentFallingShape->setBlocksOnMap( * map );
        lastUpdateLinesCleared = clearFullLines();
    }
    timeUntilShapeDrop = calculateShapeDropTimeInterval();
```

I also included gradual shape animation if you're interested one way of how to do it. I built a graphical game map on top of the logical map and used the logical map to start the graphical interpolation. I broke the graphics library I was using, but the logic code is still good for reference or use if you'd like.